# XCode 4 accidentally deleted product file

Tags: xcode

I'm using XCode and Appcode for developing.
In Appcode, accidentally I deleted the .app file from the Products folder.

After that I can build the project successfully in both IDE, but can't run on simulator or device, when the build finished, nothing happening.
The .app file created on the derived data directory fine, like earlier so that's not the problem.
If I check the debug scheme in XCode, on the Executable list None is chosen, if I browse the generated app in the derived data directory and set that, then works fine, run on simulator and device too, but the app file not shown in the Products folder and after a restart, XCode set the Executables back to None, which is annoying.

How can I set back the .app file to show in the Products directory in XCode and work like earlier?

Comment: You aren't backing up your project directory?

Comment: No, it's just a test project, but contains lot of little settings, so I don't want to create another one.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to delete the "product" file in my own test project by going to the Project Settings and then clicking on the app under "Targets" and touching the "Delete" key.

[image: What We See When We Have No Target]

To create a new Target, go back to Project Settings and click the "Add Target" button.

Normally, this means you need to reset *all* of your settings, but if you have the original target's Info.plist (settings) file around, you may be able to pick up some of your previous target's settings from there.

[image: And You Can Create a New Target]

Comment: Thx, but I didn't delete the target, I have that, only the app file was deleted from the products folder.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue.

If we are building for the SIMULATOR - then the Target file still "not-included". Change from the top build actions for - ProjectName>iOS Device (instead of the ios Simulator) then the project target file gets generated and is included in the project folder hierarchy.

There is no need to run - just rebuild and that should do the trick